# JNI setup with eclipse

Tags: eclipse, java-native-interface

how can I include the jni.h library in eclipse? Which plugin has to be installed?

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jni.h is in your JDK; I wouldn't install it in a plugin, but rather just set up an external dependency to it.

Comment: I dont think so. When I write "#include <jni.h>" it says I have an unresolved inclusion, so it can't be in the JDK.

Comment: Yes, it's definitely in the JDK (in the "include" subdirectory) -- it's just that the CDT tools aren't set up to look there by default. You need to add that to your include path in the project set-up.